# Show that the function defined by means of the following equations is entire

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)=(1-cos(z))/z^2$ when $z \neq 0$ , $1/2$ when $z=0$

Approach: The book gives a hint which consists in expressing the numerator in terms of power series and then dividing these power series by z^2. I have to show that the resulting series is convergent no matter what z is.

$$cos(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

so

$$\frac{1-cos(z)}{z^2}= \frac{1-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}}{z^2}$$

but the problem is the $1/z^2$ and if I expand $1/z^2$, I would have to constrain it to $|z-2|<2$ which is not good since the series must be convergent for any z

Comment: What is the first term in the series expansion for $\cos(z)$?

Comment: XD it's 1, so it cancels out. Thank you!

Comment: No worries mate.